# child element expand parent height (100%)

Tags: html, css

I try to create a full screen website (without scrollbar and with 100% height)
I have a div with 90% height of the page. And i want to put elements inside dynamically.
My problem is, when to many elements inside this div, they expand the parent height. And because the "overscroll:hidden" property on the body, the half page is out of the monitor.
I created an example for the problem:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqP9g/1/)

If you remove the `class="textBox"` elements, you can see how could be look like.
I tried to add `overflow:scroll` property to the parent div, but it doesn't help, and the `max-height:100%` either.

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left">
    <div id="something">valami</div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="parent">
        <ul id="container">
            <li>
               <ul class="group">
                    <li class="textBox">
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                    </li>
                    <li class="textBox">
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                    </li>
                    <li class="textBox">
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                        lorem ipsum<br />
                    </li> 
               </ul> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="bottomContainer">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#left, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
#left {
    background-color: red;
}
#parent {
    padding: 50px 0 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#container li {
     max-height: inherit;
}
#bottomContainer {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.group {
    padding: 10px;
}
.textBox {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: display:table = no scroll because element will expand/shrink according to content hold. height here can be seen as min-height only. display:table and such will not show scrollbar anyhow, just like display:inline, any other display value + height might produce a scrollbar when needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you were looking for, but moving the `overflow: auto` property to `#parent` seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/YqP9g/2/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#left, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
#left {
    background-color: red;
}
#parent {
    padding: 50px 0 150px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container {
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
#bottomContainer {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.group {
    padding: 10px;
}
.textBox {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's almost what i want, but i want to place the scroll bar in the #container element.

Comment: i could use this, to modify my code, to work, thanks!

Comment: I threw together another version of how I would have styled this.  I find it easiest to work with absolute positioning in situations like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YqP9g/5/

I also did a version in which I moved the bottomContainer outside of the #container, which made styling a bit easier: http://jsfiddle.net/YqP9g/4/

Answer (score 0):

[updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqP9g/3/)

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
#left, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
#left {
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#right {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
#parent {
    padding: 50px 0 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
}
#container li {
     max-height: inherit;
}
#bottomContainer {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.group {
    padding: 10px;
}
.textBox {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```